# Restrict HQL query to parent class only

Tags: java, hibernate

I have two classes A and B. B extends A. I want to update via HQL class A. B is mapped as table per concrete class. I have no control over the mappings. So I can't introduce a new abstract class for instance.

"Update A set attr1=1" will Update class A and B as far as I know. Is it possible to update via HQL only class A? Can I prevent the creation of temporary bulk update tables with a special crafted HQL?

```
public class A {
  ...
}


public class B extends A {
   ...
}

session.createQuery("Update A set attr1=1").executeUpdate();


<hibernate-mapping auto-import="false" default-
  cascade="none" default-access="property" default-lazy="true">
    <class name="A" table="a" abstract="false" 
        polymorphism="implicit" dynamic-update="false" dynamic-insert="false" select-before-update="false">
         <id name="id" column="id"/>       
         <property name="attr1" column="attr1" unique="false" optimistic-lock="true" lazy="false" generated="never"/>           

     </class>
</hibernate-mapping>

<hibernate-mapping auto-import="false" default-cascade="none" default-access="property" default-lazy="true">
    <union-subclass name="B" table="b" batch-size="20" extends="A" dynamic-update="false" dynamic-insert="false" select-before-update="false">


        <property name="attr2" column="attr2" unique="false" optimistic-lock="true" lazy="false" generated="never"/>
    </union-subclass>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: are you using `cascade = CascadeType.ALL`, can you please share your code so we can understand more?

Comment: I added some sample code. I think cascade matters only for association's but not for inheritance.

Comment: well if `B extends A`, then `Update A set attr1=1` will affect `B`as well as it inherits from `A` , this is how inheritance works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I did come up with the following solution. I can't change class A or B. I have no control over A.hbm or B.hbm, but I can monkey patch hibernate configuration at runtime.

I created a new class APatched:

```
  class APatched extends A {
  }
```

Added a APatched.hbm mapping file:

```
 <hibernate-mapping auto-import="false" default-cascade="none" default-access="property" default-lazy="true">
<union-subclass name="APatched" table="not_existing" batch-size="20" extends="A" dynamic-update="false" dynamic-insert="false" select-before-update="false">



</union-subclass>
```

and monkey patched Hibernate configuration before Hibernate starts:

```
  configuration.addResource('APatched.hbm');
  configuration.buildMappings();
  PersistentClass toBePatched = configuration.getClassMapping(A.class.getName());
  String oldTableName = toBePatched.getTable().getName();
  toBePatched.getTable().setName(oldTableName + "_patched_not_existing");
  toBePatched.getTable().setAbstract(true);
  toBePatched.setAbstract(true);

  PersistentClass patched = configuration.getClassMapping(APatched.class.getName());
  patched.getTable().setName(oldTableName);
```

I changed my HQL to:

```
 session.createQuery("Update APatched set attr1=1").executeUpdate();
```

This way I was able to inject the missing concept within the original modeled classes and prevent the usage of temporary tables during hibernate multi-table bulk operations.